# JPA Repository - Getting duplicates in List caused by table joins

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am having a very difficult situation and yet the situation is very complex and hard to find similar case in stackoverflow.

I have the following entities

Store

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class Store implements IModel {

  @Id
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "storestatus", nullable = false)
  private StoreStatus storeStatus = StoreStatus.UNKNOWN;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "storetypecode_id")
  private StoreTypeCode storeTypeCode;

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "store")
  private Address address;

  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "store")
  private Set<StoreTranslation> storeTranslationList = new HashSet<>();

  public Store() {

  }
```

StoreTypeCode

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "storetypecode")
public class StoreTypeCode implements IModel {

  @Id
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;

  @Column(name = "displaysort", nullable = false)
  private Integer displaySort = 999;

  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "storeTypeCode")
  private Set<StoreTypeCodeTranslation> storeTypeCodeTranslationList = new HashSet<>();


  public StoreTypeCode() {
  }

}
```

And StoreCategory

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "storeitemcategory")
public class StoreItemCategory implements IModel {

  @Id
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "store_id")
  private Store store;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "storeitemcategory_storeitem",
      joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "storeitemcategory_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
      inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "storeitem_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
  private List<StoreItem> storeItems = new ArrayList<>();

  @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "storeItemCategory")
  private Set<StoreItemCategoryTranslation> storeItemCategoryTranslationList = new HashSet<>();



  public StoreItemCategory() {
  }


  public void addStoreItem(StoreItem storeItem) {
    this.storeItems.add(storeItem);
  }
}
```

With the above relationship, here is what I have.

Store A with storeTypeCode ("Cafe") and storeItemCategory ("Iced drinks")
StoreTypeCode has two translations 1) for English, 2) for Chinese.

Whenever I add an item to storeItems in StoreItemCategory, I get duplicates in the list. (And multiple duplicate records are inserted to 'storeitemcategory_storeitem' table.)

```java
      StoreItemCategory sic = storeItemCategoryRepository.findById(storeItemCategoryid).get();
      sic.addStoreItem(new StoreItem(...));
      sic = storeItemCategoryRepository.save(sic);
```

I suspect this has something to do with the way tables are joined for translations because when I run a query created from Spring for getting StoreItemCategory, I get multiple records of StoreItemCategory (one for English and one for Chinese from StoreTypeCode).

```sql
select
       *
    from
        storeitemcategory storeitemc0_
    left outer join
        store store1_
            on storeitemc0_.store_id=store1_.id
    left outer join
        storetranslation storetrans2_
            on store1_.id=storetrans2_.store_id
    left outer join
        storetypecode storetypec3_
            on store1_.storetypecode_id=storetypec3_.id
    left outer join
        storetypecodetranslation storetypec4_
            on storetypec3_.id=storetypec4_.storetypecode_id
    left outer join
        address address5_
            on store1_.id=address5_.store_id
    left outer join
        storeitemcategorytranslation storeitemc6_
            on storeitemc0_.id=storeitemc6_.storeitemcategory_id
    left outer join
        storeitemcategory_storeitem storeitems7_
            on storeitemc0_.id=storeitems7_.storeitemcategory_id
    left outer join
        storeitem storeitem8_
            on storeitems7_.storeitem_id=storeitem8_.id
    left outer join
        store store9_
            on storeitem8_.store_id=store9_.id
    left outer join
        storeitemtranslation storeitemt10_
            on storeitem8_.id=storeitemt10_.storeitem_id
    where
        storeitemc0_.id=?
```

All my tables will have translations tables and I am not sure how to get-around with this without using set.

Does anyone have similar experience?

Comment: Your issue is Duplicate record is being saved or duplicate record is being fetched?

Comment: Duplicate records are fetched.  But because duplicate records are fetched, when adding a new record, it saves the fetched duplicated records

Comment: Please add your fetch query code, query which you have added is from log generated internally,

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? If yes which version? One workaround would be to make `storeItems` a `Set`.

Comment: Another solution is if you use JPA2.1 try entity graphs